# Android Studio 3 debug on kitkat device Logcat not showing source reference

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, missing-data, android-logcat

When debugging on an older Samsung GT-P5210 Android 4.4.2 Tablet the logcat
when app crash is showen in Logcat but, it´s like it´s missing information.

In the Log there´s usually some link directly to offending source file 
but not in this log.

I look in the Tablet developer option setting but cant see anything controlling this, I think this is some settings in Android Studio 3 for older apis, How to fix this?

```
    03-25 16:49:43.108 29697-30049/com.game.android.debug E/UncaughtException: 
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ROUTE
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.i$a.<init>(SourceFile:791)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.a(SourceFile:817)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:886)
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:825)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.b.a(SourceFile:55)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.a(SourceFile:51)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.b(SourceFile:47)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.c.a(SourceFile:60)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a.a(SourceFile:47)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.a(SourceFile:229)
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.performFiltering(SourceFile:104)
       at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ROUTE
       at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:724)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.i$a.<init>(SourceFile:780)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.a(SourceFile:817) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164) 
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:886) 
       at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:825) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.b.a(SourceFile:55) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.a(SourceFile:51) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.b(SourceFile:47) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.c.a(SourceFile:60) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a.a(SourceFile:47) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.a(SourceFile:229) 
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.performFiltering(SourceFile:104) 
       at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
03-25 16:49:43.678 29697-29697/com.game.android.debug E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.publishResults(SourceFile:140)
       at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:49:43.978 29697-30049/com.game.android.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Filter
Process: com.game.android.debug, PID: 29697
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ROUTE
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.i$a.<init>(SourceFile:791)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.a(SourceFile:817)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:886)
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:825)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.b.a(SourceFile:55)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.a(SourceFile:51)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.b(SourceFile:47)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.c.a(SourceFile:60)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a.a(SourceFile:47)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.a(SourceFile:229)
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.performFiltering(SourceFile:104)
    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ROUTE
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:724)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.i$a.<init>(SourceFile:780)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.a(SourceFile:817) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:53) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:115) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:164) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:100) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:423) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:886) 
    at com.google.gson.f.a(SourceFile:825) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.b.a(SourceFile:55) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.a(SourceFile:51) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a$1.b(SourceFile:47) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.c.a(SourceFile:60) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.a.a(SourceFile:47) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.c.a(SourceFile:229) 
    at com.game.android.PlacesProvider.a.e.performFiltering(SourceFile:104) 
    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows the information present in the APK that caused the Exception. If it misses the source file name, this means that these information had been removed from the APK, e.g. by a code obfuscator.

If you have the source code of the app you should create a debug build or a release build without obfuscation.

If you don't have the source code of the app there is nothing you can do on your own. You can only contact the app author and describe the problem.

Comment: Yea it looks like obfuscation, this started happen after i update to play-services 12.0.0 in the build.gradle file. I was debugging ok before this update, on the old kitkat device

Comment: I have two other devices where debug works normal, but not on the Samsung GT-P5210 Android 4.4.2 Tablet